# Parsing an XML file and storing it in a HashMap

Tags: hashmap, saxparser, domparser

I have an xml file with a size of about 130 KB. Currently this XML file is parsed using a DOM parser on start up of the application. I want to know if its a good idea to parse the entire XML using a SAX parser and then store them in a HashMap. 
This HashMap would be an instance variable in a class and as and when any information is required to be read from the XML this map would be used.

Is this a good idea to parse the entire XML using SAX parser and store all of the information in a HashMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are keeping whole file in hashmap and the file size is less. It does not matter which parser you use. If the file size would have been larger which you cannot load in one instance you need to use SAX-parser instead of DOM-parser. As SAX parser only chunk of data from file reading them character by character. While as DOM loads whole file in one go.